# Erb from database and image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, erb

Just stumbled upon a problem and to the moment, cannot solve it. So here's the setting:

I have an ERB template fetched from the database and rendered to html

```
Class MyController < ApplicationController

  include AssetTagHelper
  ...
  def Show
    template=Page.find(...)   # <%=image_tag('Test.png')%>
    @html=ERB.new(template).result(binding)
  end
  ...
```

Now the problem is image_tag 'src' resolves into '/images/Test.png', when normally it should resolve to '/assets/Test.png'. So I looked into the rails source of [AssetTagHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb) which led me to [AssetUrlHelper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb) and the following call chain: image_path => asset_path => compute_asset_path. And compute_asset_path legitimately states it should actually resolve to /images/Test.png...

What am I missing here? How can I make the image tag work and give me 'assets/Test.png'?

Thanks in advance for all replies!

Comment: If you know what it will always need to resolve to, why not just use that?  So instead of returning .erb and then processing it before render, why not just store the html you need in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record - while debugging figured out that normally compute_asset_path is overriden in sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb

Solved the issue by moving `@html=ERB.new(template).result(binding)` from controller to view. Hope this helps somebody ))

Answer (score 1):

Like example I show how to create ERB from database for Mailer class. For another classes all same.

Completed mailer to create email templates from database:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

      # included helper
      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
      # another helpers...
      # included helper

      def mailer(from, to, subject, path, name)
        mail( from: from, to: to, subject: subject, template_path: path, template_name: name )
      end

      def get_template(template_name)
        @erb = EmailTemplate.where(name: template_name, mailer_name: UserMailer.to_s.underscore).first rescue ''
        @template_content_html = ERB.new(@erb.template_html).result(binding).html_safe rescue ''
        @template_content_text = ERB.new(@erb.template_text).result(binding).html_safe rescue ''
      end

      def test(user_id)
        from = 'from@mail.com'
        recipients = 'to@mail.com'
        subject = "test"
        template_path = "user_mailer"
        get_template(__method__) #def
        template_name = "general"
        mailer(from, recipients, subject, template_path, template_name)
      end

    end
```

for include helper in Mailer you can use construction like this:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

works perfect from rails 3.2.13. earlier not tried.